# Override hostname for mail(1) in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, mutt, tcsh, mail-command

I'm trying to quickly send some stuff to myself from my MacBook, but I'm having issues with my server rejecting the SMTP connection due to the unqualified domain name in the from field.

I've tried using `EMAIL` env variable, with [mutt(1)](http://ports.su/mail/mutt), but I'm still getting the very same error, per `/var/log/mail.log` on my MacBook:

`Aug  1 13:32:52 MacBook-Air-01234567890.local postfix/smtp[91675]: AEA7EDD2D11: to=<-@--.-->, relay=a.mx.---.--[88.198.--.--]:25, delay=7.8, delays=0.78/0.01/6.8/0.17, dsn=5.1.8, status=bounced (host a.mx.---.--[88.198.--.--] said: 553 5.1.8 <----@MacBook-Air-01234567890.local>... Domain of sender address ----@MacBook-Air-01234567890.local does not exist (in reply to MAIL FROM command))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`ports/mail/mutt`](http://ports.su/mail/mutt) solution:

This is because `mutt` doesn't change the SMTP envelope in accordance with `EMAIL` environment variable, so, the following must be used instead, [tcsh](http://ports.su/shells/tcsh) syntax:

```
env EMAIL=`whoami`@`hostname`.example.org \
mutt -s "`history 1`" -e 'set envelope_from' email@example.org
```

Basically, you gotta not only specify your email in the environmental variable `EMAIL`, but also pass `-e 'set envelope_from'` to [`mutt`](http://ports.su/mail/mutt), which defaults to `no`, as per http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#use-envelope-from.

---

## [`mail(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/mail.1) solution:

Another option is to use the fact [`mail(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/mail.1) command [lets](http://bxr.su/n/usr.bin/mail/mail.1) you pass any *`sendmail-flags`* ***past*** the specification of the *`to-addr`*:

```
 mail [-EIinv] [-a file] [-b bcc-addr] [-c cc-addr] [-r rcfile]
      [-s subject] to-addr ... [- sendmail-flags]
```

This appears to be explicitly documented with the `-f` example only in the [NetBSD's manual page for mail(1)](http://mdoc.su/n/mail.1), not in [OpenBSD's](http://mdoc.su/o/mail.1), [FreeBSD's](http://mdoc.su/f/mail.1), OS X or macOS' ones:

```
   Sending mail
     To send a message to one or more people, mail can be invoked with argu-
     ments which are the names of people to whom the mail will be sent.  You
     are then expected to type in your message, followed by a `control-D' at
     the beginning of a line.

     Any flags following the list of recipients, will be passed, together with
     their arguments, directly to sendmail(1).  For example to change your
     From address to somebody@somewhere.net you can specify:

           mail recipient -f somebody@somewhere.net
```

E.g., the following would work the same way as the `mutt` example above; successfully tested on OS X:

```
mail -s "`history 1`" email@example.org -f `whoami`@`hostname`.example.org
```

N. B.  The order does matter; and <strike>`mail -f wrong@example.org -s subject email@example.org`</strike> won't work; see details above!